# Attempting to display binary data as a jpeg on the browser

Tags: javascript, html

The source for my data is here: http://pastebin.com/raw/eww0Mb6x

I'm calling a simple set of functions:

```
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(attachment.data);
            document.body.appendChild(img);
```

`attachment.data` is what is present in the pastebin. My image is coming out broken. Any suggestions to make it work?

UPDATE:

I tried both `img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;,' + attachment.data;` and `img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + attachment.data;` but I'm still getting a broken image.

Comment: If your attachment.data = pastebin, then your data is already encoded.  You are encoding it twice, which of course doesn't work.

Comment: how sure are you that data is correct? This doesn't seem to be able to decode it either http://base64online.org/decode/

Comment: I'm calling the gmail API to do it. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get

Comment: Your code is correct. It's just that what you've pasted in Pastebin can't be parsed as image. Check your source.

Comment: It's so confusing though. This is an object returned from ```gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get...```. It can read the filename, type, and some mystery string that represents the jpg itself. How the heck do I use this darn string?

Comment: Look at row response for example in FireBug. It may help.